# Add to NSMutableArray during fast enumeration

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

As the title goes I am looking to find out how you would add. The code I current have looks like this, though it fails to add simple to the bakeryProductArray per loop. I know you would use (i) if it was a traditional for loop but what would you do in an instance like this?

```
for (PFObject *song in food) {

    PFObject *simple = [song objectForKey:@"Name"];

   [bakeryProductArray addObject: simple];
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Did you initialize `bakeryProductArray`? Does `food` have any objects in it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code fragment as such, assuming all the variables are of the types and values expected. You need to provide more detail, about what the problem is, what you've tried to fix it, and the context of the code fragment.

Comment: Sorted cheers @rmaddy I hadn't initialized it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't initialized the bakeryProductArray. Its working now.

Comment: I had the same problem before, and it took me a few hours to find out:>

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking I haven't done something right. When it's something petty. :D